# how to fix cannot convert int to boolean

Tags: java

```
package com.mime.WorldExplorer.graphics;

import java.util.Random;

public class Screen extends Render {

    private Render test;


    public Screen(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
        Random random = new Random();
        test = new Render(256, 256);
        for (int i = 0; 256*256; i++ ) {
            test.pixels[i] = random.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
for (int i = 0; 256*256; i++ )
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256*256; i++ )
```

According to [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), one way to declare the `for` loop is:

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
```

where:

- The `initialization` expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
- When the `termination` expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
- The `increment` expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

So, `termination` should be a condition that evaluates to a `boolean`, not an integer.